# Automate the Cloudformation template Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am currently using Cloudformation templates to provision resources in AWS.

Currently, if I need to create a VPC and Security groups, First I will create VPC from a template and again I will launch another template for security group where I manually input the VPC ID.

Now, I need to automate this manual process in Cloudformation. How can I do this? Can I use AWS Developer tools or other automation tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

You need to follow a practice of outputting the ARNs/Names of any AWS resources that you create so if you need them later on, you can easily do that by a simple reference by doing an import in the new template.

As explained in the answer above by Nimo, for this, you will need to use the `Export` function in the `Outputs` section for all templates for any resources that you expect might be reused. And then later you can easily use `Fn::ImportValue` to use a previously created resource, without knowing the actual physical ID of the resource. This is called cross-stack referencing.

### Explanation for the automation part

It seems like you need Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment **(CICD)** for your infrastructure so your code changes will be deployed directly/automatically to AWS. You will have to set up pipelines for this and following is the simplest but not the only way:

1. Use Github/AWS codecommit etc. for storing your CloudFormation code
   and set its trigger to a branch e.g. your `master` branch so any
   changes in it will trigger the pipeline and it will deploy those
   changes automatically.
2. Use AWS's native service AWS CodePipeline for this purpose. This is
   where you can define a complete pipeline with various stages while each stage may have many actions and each creating a stack. All stacks may use outputs from the previously created stacks and some stuff can be passed into the parameters as well. For this, you will have to create a new stack with `AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline` as a resource.
3. Use outputs also for the resources without the export function for
   those resources which you think you will need. Like for example, you
   might want the load balancer's DNS endpoint, if you have one.

Here is a [Reference Pipeline Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html#aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline--examples) which uses s3 as the source for the stored code.

Comment: I got what you said. Can you give me some extra document references so that I can follow it for my solution in practical?

Comment: Added a link to a reference Pipeline stack that you can tweak around your needs. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey @DeependraDangal! If this answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough information.  If you are using CICD, for example jenkins.

You can specify output variables in your cloud-formation template, that can be referenced by other templates.

So you could have something like.

```
Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: Unique-VpcId
```

and then import it in another stack like

```
VpcId:
    Fn::ImportValue: Unique-VpcId
```

Comment: I want to use CI/CD, but not Jenkins. I want to use AWS Developer tools(code commit, codebuild,codedeploy and codepipeline.

Comment: The principal is the same.  export your variables and then reference them in your next template.