# CI / CD using Bitbucket repository for resource provisioning in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-cloudformation

I want to achieve a Continuous delivery for provisioning AWS resources using Bitbucket & AWS. My use case is to create a kinesis Firehose Delivery stream with destination as Elastic Search. I want this to be achieved by using the AWS cloudformation templates (keeping in mind the different stages for dev, uat, prod). Whenever I update my bitbucket repo the build should get created and the stack will get updated in AWS. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I have searched a lot over the internet but could not find any relevant examples which clearly describes my use case.

Cloudformatiom template committed in bitbucket will provision AWS resources in the cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS CodePipeline for this purpose. The only issue is that Code Pipeline does not work directly with Bitbucket, only works with [AWS CodeCommit or GitHub](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/integrating-git-with-aws-codepipeline/) as the triggering repo.

**But** there is a workaround for that. You can set up syncing from Bitbucket to GitHub and then set the GitHub repository as the source repository for the pipeline you will create on AWS CodePipeline. You can find many guides for syncing so I won't explain here. The pipeline itself can be defined as a template.

I have already explained Setting up AWS CodePipeline in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56209164/5722394) that you can follow for this purpose. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but my problem is that I have to achieve this with only using bitbucket , cannot use git. I think AWS Codebuild can be integrated with bitbucket repo so can that be used as an alternate solution. i.e. Bitbucket Repo -> AWS CodeBuild -> AWS CodeDeploy -> AWS CodePipeline

Comment: AWS CodeBuild is not a git service, for the source repository you should use AWS Code Commit then. If you're asking for the application code to be deployed alongside the infrastructure (CloudFormation) then yes, you can deploy the application part through code deploy within the same pipeline. BUT the question you asked is about resource provisioning on AWS.

Comment: In that case, After the successful deployment of EC2 instances for example, you can trigger the code deploy action to deploy the application as well on the instances. This will be deployment stage to me. Everything in code pipeline is a stage and inside you can find actions. I suggest going through the documentation of these services and then if you have questions to implement something, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not going to deploy any application code , but only cloudtransformation templates to provision AWS resoources. These templates I would like to store in bitbucket repository and whenever anyone commit changes to master branch , the build should get triggered and stack should get updated in AWS. This is what I want to achieve with bitcucket & cloudformation templates. Let me know if you have any approach for it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Then the answer above is exactly what you need. AWS CodePipeline is the best for doing this, I'm already using it in production. But the only caveat is that Code Pipeline does not let us use bitbucket repository as a source to trigger the pipeline so you can use AWS Codecommit in the pipeline source and set up your  CodeCommit/Github repository to sync with bitbucket. So whenever someone makes changes and commits to bit bucket, this will immediately reflect on CodeCommit or GitHub (whatever you chose) and then the pipeline will be triggered.